# How can I show UserID of Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to try the following API.

User - Get Shared Access Token ( API Management )
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/getsharedaccesstoken

But I can't discover my UserID. It's maybe 24 characters string.
How can I show that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the `userId` via powershell or rest api.

1.Use powershell : [`Get-AzApiManagementUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementuser?view=azps-1.6.0)

```
$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName >" -ServiceName "<API Management service name>"
Get-AzApiManagementUser -Context $ApiMgmtContext
```

The command will list all the users, find the one you want,  the `UserId` in the result is that.

[image]

2.Use rest api : [`User - List By Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/listbyservice)

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}/users?api-version=2018-06-01-preview
```

The `name` in the result is what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! the Rest API is the easiest way for me. It worked well! Thank you very much.

Comment: Or use UI. Navigate to users blade, press Columns button to open columns chooser and select either "Id" for full resource id, or "name" for last segment of id.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) to fin your user id.

subscriptions-> your subscription-> resourceGroups -> your resource group -> providers ->
Microsoft.ApiManagement -> service -> your ApiManagement service -> users

[image]

The name tag is your userID and the 1 is the default Administrator user id.

Comment: I'm sorry for replying so late. Thank you very much. Your advice `1  is the default Administrator user id` was useful for me.